# How to convert Humdrum files to Lilypond format?

Tags: lilypond, musicxml

I have some [Humdrum krn score files](https://www.humdrum.org/rep/kern/) and want to make [Lilypond](https://lilypond.org/) files out of it for further processing and output generation.

What ist the best way to do this?

I tried the user interface Frescobaldi but there is no import option.

Has anybody experiences in converting this way?

- from .krn to music-xml using [Humdrum's `hum2xml` export](http://extras.humdrum.org/man/hum2xml/) and then
- from .xml to .ly using [Lilypond's `musicxml2ly` import](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/usage/invoking-musicxml2ly.de.html)

Comment: I don't have any experience with lilypond and humdrum but If you have experience with Linux maybe you check [this](https://github.com/craigsapp/hum2ly) one :

Answer (score 2):

Found a review paper of music notation conversions including humdrum to Lilypond: "The Effects of Translation Between Symbolic Music Formats: A Case Study with Humdrum, Lilypond, MEI, and MusicXML" presented at the 2019 Music Encoding Conference in Vienna.

It should be possible. However, the conversions tested in the paper give results that are not very good